# How to sanatize a command for security

Tags: python, bash, shell, security, filtering

I am making a Discord bot in Python. I have some cool commands installed on my shell (like `cowsay`) that I want to be implemented into the bot, so I have this code near the end:

````
else:                                                 
            for i in bash_cmds:
                if digested.startswith(prefix + i):
                    cmd = digested.replace(prefix, '')
                    msg = os.popen(cmd).read()
                    msg = '```' + msg + '```'
                    await client.send_message(channel, msg)
````

So basically, if it starts with `!!` + any of the BASh commands I've added in an array `["cowsay", "cowthink", "fortune", "echo"]`, then execute the command in the shell. However, this brings up some security problems. For example, one could write `echo hackscript | bash` or `nc -l 1337` or `cat *` or `rm *` (you get the point).

I have started a list of commands that I don't want to occur in the command. However, I don't want an error to prevent the succesful part of the message not to be seen. (If someone put `cowsay foo && ls`, I still want the output of `cowsay foo` to appear.)

How would I be able to filter out possibly malicious commands and allow the unfiltered part of a message to succeed?

---

I thought that replacing things like `;`s and `&`s would work, but I want to leave some things like `$()` available so people can use `cowsay $(fortune)`, but then people would be able to do things like `echo $(ls)`... But I don't want to filter out commands either, because: 
a. There could be ways around it and
b. I don't want `I eat 3 meals a day` to turn into `I eat three mea a day`...

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?

Comment: I think this question is really "how do I sanitize terminal input to limit input to several commands ". I don't know if it should be downvoted but the question could be narrowed a bit. I guess you could just ask "how do I ensure any command is pure string" but I don't know for sure

Comment: I thought that replacing things like `;`s and `&`s would work, but I want to leave some things like `$()` available so people can use `cowsay $(fortune)`, but then people would be able to do things like `echo $(ls)`... But I don't want to filter out commands either, because: a. There could be ways around it and b. I don't want `I eat 3 meals a day` to turn into `I eat three mea a day`...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [restricted shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html). You can then create a `.bash_profile` that sets `$PATH` to a directory that contains only the bins that you want to be executed by the bot.

Comment: You can change the shell that `popen` uses by setting the `executable` keyword argument

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking to call something like https://docs.python.org/dev/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote on the argument